# How to create download page with countdown in wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I'm working on a WordPress project and aiming to create a download page similar to "[APK Material Download](https://apkmaterial.com/)" with a countdown timer before users can access the download link. I've explored plugins and attempted to use JavaScript/jQuery, but haven't found a suitable solution yet.

What I've Tried:

Explored various WordPress plugins for download pages with countdowns. Attempted to implement a countdown timer using JavaScript/jQuery, but not similar result achieve.

What I'm Looking For:

I seek guidance on how to efficiently implement a download page with a countdown timer in WordPress. If anyone has experience with plugins or custom code for achieving this functionality, I'd appreciate any insights, recommendations, or code snippets.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Can you provide some of the code you're working with?  Is the countdown arbitrary?  Are you just saying "it take 30 seconds for the download to happen" or are you setting the download link availability after X based on condition Y?  All of these details change the way this is going to function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.